# I am having package related issue in Android image button

Tags: android

I am having same issue again and again. I am new to Android studio. But I managed it somehow.

Now whenever I implement any listener in my program it gives me an error.
For example I created a view with four image button. Now after clicking on any button it will call another activity. This is what I am trying to do. 
But when I applied

```
B1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

It gives me error:

> "SetOnClickListener(Android.  view. View. OnClickListener)  in View cannot be applied to (Com. Example. Sir. Stc. Mainactivity),

What should I do now?

Comment: ***What should I do now?*** Post some code!

Comment: `What should I do now?` [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Read this: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjACahUKEwiP8fqpsYXHAhVLH44KHWCYDNk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FButton.html&ei=CWy7Vc_ICcu-uATgsLLIDQ&usg=AFQjCNHFjRh74FWTQnf2CDSxBnX7msjm_Q&sig2=_jI-GLIziQEBwRhcOqsppg&bvm=bv.99261572,d.c2E

Comment: post your activity code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that B1 is an Instance of Mainactivity.
Check if B1 is an instance of a View and 'this' implements the OnClickListener

Comment: No he is passing instance of activity in SetOnClickListener